# How to place Aspx file link to website

Tags: asp.net

I have a psychic business.  But the link is an aspx file for online reader info.  And a jpeg list for photos 
How to I code them to make them live? To I convert to HTML? Gave up with weebly and I have a wordpress site.  Been told I probably need a computer programmer for this.  Any help or info would be fantastic!

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Tried Iframe. Code.  Really not clued up truth be told